# Unwanted whitespace left after having removed element from pretty-printed XML

Tags: python, lxml

I am new with LXML and I have a problem after parsing my element : its architecture seems to have changed if I remove (or replace) the last child.
Here is my code.

(sorry i'm new in stackoverflow so I cannot post images)

I have looked up for solution but I still can't figure what I am doing wrong.
I would really appreciate someone's help !
(I am using LXML 3.2.1 with Python 2.6 on Windows)

```
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy

def Write( file, element ):
    f = open( file, 'w' )
    f.write( etree.tostring( element, xml_declaration=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1", pretty_print = True ) )
    f.close()
    return 1

def ReadAndReturn( file ):
    lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup()
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover = True)
    parser.set_element_class_lookup( lookup )
    mainTree = etree.parse( file, parser )
    return mainTree

# create a root element with 3 children
root = etree.Element( "root" )
root.append( etree.Element( "child1" ) )
child2 = etree.SubElement( root, "child2" )
child2.text = 'CHILD2'
child3 = etree.SubElement( root, "child3" )
child3.text = 'CHILD3'

print "\n--- INITIAL ROOT ---"
print( etree.tostring( root, pretty_print=True ) )

# remove last child
root2 = deepcopy( root )
root2.remove( root2[2] )

print "--- ROOT WITHOUT LAST CHILD / BEFORE WRITING ---"
print( etree.tostring( root2, pretty_print=True ) )


# write initial root (3 children) and read the file
filename = 'test.tst'
status = Write( filename, root )
tree = ReadAndReturn( filename )

# remove last child from the read element
root3 = deepcopy( tree.getroot() )
root3.remove( root3[2] )

print "--- ROOT WITHOUT LAST CHILD / AFTER WRITING AND PARSING ---"
print( etree.tostring( root3, pretty_print=True ) )
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "its architecture seems to have changed...". What architecture?

Comment: architecture meant if we display the root (or write it in a file), we have the </root> placed as a the last child of <root> instead of being placed at the same "level" (no tab)

Comment: answer given on another forum : the problem comes for "child2" 's tail. I guess a way to solve this is to save "child3" 's tail, then remove "child3", and finally assign the saved tail as "child2" 's tail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace handling can be tricky. Here is a simplified version of your program that demonstrates what's going on.

```
from lxml import etree

# Create a root element with 3 children 
root = etree.Element( "root" )
root.append( etree.Element( "child1" ) )
child2 = etree.SubElement( root, "child2" )
child2.text = 'CHILD2'
child3 = etree.SubElement( root, "child3" )
child3.text = 'CHILD3'

# Print the "ugly" XML (no whitespace)
print "\n--- UGLY ---"
print etree.tostring(root)

# Print the "pretty" XML
print "\n--- PRETTY ---"
pp = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
print pp

# Parse the pretty XML
tree = etree.fromstring(pp) 

# remove last child
tree.remove(tree[2])

print "--- WITHOUT LAST CHILD PART 1 ---"
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)

# Parse the pretty XML once again with parser option 'remove_blank_text=True'
tree = etree.fromstring(pp, etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)) 

# remove last child
tree.remove(tree[2])

print "--- WITHOUT LAST CHILD PART 2 ---"
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
--- UGLY ---
<root><child1/><child2>CHILD2</child2><child3>CHILD3</child3></root>

--- PRETTY ---
<root>
  <child1/>
  <child2>CHILD2</child2>
  <child3>CHILD3</child3>
</root>

--- WITHOUT LAST CHILD PART 1 ---
<root>
  <child1/>
  <child2>CHILD2</child2>
  </root>

--- WITHOUT LAST CHILD PART 2 ---
<root>
  <child1/>
  <child2>CHILD2</child2>
</root>
```

The `child2` element in the pretty-printed XML document has a `.tail` property that consists of `\n` followed by two spaces. You can check this via `repr(pp)`. The two spaces are what's causing the `</root>` end tag to be misaligned.

If the pretty-printed XML document is parsed with the parser option `remove_blank_text=True`, then there will be no disrupting whitespace-only element tails and the last ("PART 2") pretty-print will work as expected.

See also:

- http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options
- http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-about-that-trailing-text-on-serialised-elements.

Comment: thanks a lot for the parser option (remove_blank_text). It works fine with it, except that now, I have 2 spaces between an element and its children instead of one tabulation. Not such a big deal but still, if I could keep my tabs, I would be very happy :)